# Why are the two calculations of $\int \frac{d x}{x \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}$ give distinct answers?

Tags: calculus, integration

Method 1:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\int\frac{d x}{x \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}=\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{2} x^{2} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)^{2}}} \\
=\int \frac{-d\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)^{2}}}=-\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}
\end{array}
$$
Method 2:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=\int( \frac{2 x}{\sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}-\frac{\sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}{x} )d x \\
let \ y=\sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}\\
=\int \frac{d x^{2}}{\sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}-\int\frac{y^{2}}{y^{2}+1} d y \\
={\sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}}-y+\arctan y\\
=\arctan \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}
\end{array}
$$
Does $\arctan \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1} =-\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}$?

Comment: $\int dx= x, $ $\int dx =x+1$ Besides in your example solving $2x^2-1>0$ results in two disjoint regions.

Comment: @MuhammetYAĞCIOĞLU, you should just post this as an answer.

Comment: @MuhammetYAĞCIOĞLU  Plug in $x=1.$ You get $-\pi/4=\pi/4.$

Comment: ***(Posting as a comment as I'm not quite sure.)*** $$ $$ I think the very first step is wrong.
$$ \int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{2x^2 - 1}}\color{blue}{ \bf\not =} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt2x^2\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2x}\right)^2}}$$
because $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, not just '$x$'.$$$$
The correct simplification would be, $$\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{2x^2 - 1}} = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt2x |x|\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2x}\right)^2}}$$
This integral [simplifies to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5xXx.png) $\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2x^2 - 1}\right) + C$.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer could be $\arccos {1\over x\sqrt{2}}$ for $x>{1\over \sqrt{2}}.$ Hence $$\arctan \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}=\arccos {1\over x\sqrt{2}}+ c, \ \ x>{1\over \sqrt{2}}$$ Plugging in $x=1$ or taking the limit when $x\to {1\over \sqrt{2}}^+$ gives $c=0.$ Hence
$$\arctan \sqrt{2 x^{2}-1}=\arccos {1\over x\sqrt{2}}, \quad x>{1\over \sqrt{2}}$$ By symmetry the equality extends to $|x|>{1\over \sqrt{2}}.$

The answer can be written in terms of $\arcsin$ as $$\arcsin x + \arccos x={\pi\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan^{-1} \sqrt{2x^2-1}=t \implies \tan t =\sqrt{2c^2-1}\implies t=\cos^{-1} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2}}$

The value of indefinite integrals is always uncertain by am additive constant.

Comment: By two additive constants in this case. Plug in $x=-1$ in your answer.